# Showing that a partitioned matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Consider the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{3 \times 3} & & & \\
 & \frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{2 \times 2} \\
 & & \frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{3 \times 3} \\
& & & \frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{2 \times 2} \\
\end{bmatrix} + \mathbf{I}_{10}$$
where $\mathbf{I}_{10}$ is the $10 \times 10$ identity matrix, $\mathbf{1}_{n \times n}$ denotes the $n \times n$ matrix of **all** ones, and all other entries are $0$ if not given above.

Is there an easy way to see that this matrix is positive definite?

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Block_matrices), which seems (if I'm not reading this incorrectly) to suggest that a **necessary** condition for
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{3 \times 3} & & & \\
 & \frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{2 \times 2} \\
 & & \frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{3 \times 3} \\
& & & \frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{2 \times 2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
to be positive definite is that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{3 \times 3} &  \\
 & \frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}\mathbf{1}_{2 \times 2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
is positive definite as well. But since $\mathbf{I}_{10}$ is added to the entire matrix, I'm not sure if this is useful at all.

Comment: Sum of positive definite matrices is positive definite again.

Comment: @user251257 Thank you. I had a hunch that this was true, but wasn't sure. So $\mathbf{I}_{10}$ is positive definite. How would you suggest approaching the other matrix?

Comment: @user251257 And this is also true for **block** diagonal matrices?

Comment: @user251257 No; for example, $\mathbf{1}_{2 \times 2}$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix of all ones.

Comment: Oh sorry. I though that was also $I$. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A block diagonal matrix with square diagonal blocks is positive (semi)definite if each diagonal block is positive (semi)definite, as
$$ \begin{bmatrix} u\\ v \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} A & 0\\ 0 & B\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} u\\ v \end{bmatrix} = u^T A u + v^T B v. $$
Note: The eigenvalues of such a block diagonal matrix are the eigenvalues of every diagonal blocks.

Here, each diagonal block is given by $A=I_n + r ee^T$ with $r\ge 0$ and $e = (1,\dotsc,1)^T \in \mathbb R^n$. For every $x\ne 0$ we have
$$ x^T (I_n + r ee^T) x = \underbrace{x^T x}_{>0} + \underbrace{r (e^T x)^2}_{\ge 0} > 0. $$
Note: The eigenvalues of $A$ is $1$ and $1+rn$.

Comment: I follow everything here except how you were able to get the eigenvalues from a quick inspection... could you elaborate?

Comment: and another question I have is that, is it generally true that the eigenvalues of a sum of two matrices is the sum of the eigenvalues of the matrices? From what I've gathered, this isn't true in general - therefore, why is it true in this case?

Comment: @Clarinetist: I rewrote the answer with more elementary steps, without using eigenvalues. As for your question about eigenvalues of sum of matrices, they are in general not the same as the sum of the eigenvalues.